# Как сделать переменную видимой за пределами функции но и не глобальной?

Tags: javascript, jquery, область-видимости

Есть код:

```
function submenu(){
    var link = $('.menu li');
    link.hover(function () {
        if($(this).find('ul').length > 0){
            var submenu = $($(this).find('ul')[0]);
            open(submenu);
        }
    },
    function () {
        close(submenu); //не видит submenu
    }
    );
    function open(item) {
        $(item).slideDown().addClass('active');
    }
function close(item) {
    $(item).slideUp().removeClass('active');
}}
```

Как сделать видимой submenu? Если убрать var и сделать глобальной - не годится.

Comment: видимой где? лучше придумать переменной другое имя, чтобы оно не совпадало с именем функции

Comment: там есть комментарий же, видимой во втором блоке function(){...}

Comment: так и объяви ее на уровне этой функции, там же где и `var link`

Comment: да, спасибо, помогло

Comment: @Grundy это только у меня ощущение, что с вложенными списками это работать не будет?

Comment: @Igor, стоит проверить, но скорее всего да, только на последнем уровне должно работать

Answer (score 0):

Зачем Вам эта переменная?

```
function submenu(){
  $('.menu li').hover(
    function () {
      if($(this).find('ul').length > 0){
        open($(this).find('ul')[0]);
      }
    },
    function () {
      if($(this).find('ul').length > 0){
        close($(this).find('ul')[0]);
      }
    }
  );

  function open(item) {
    $(item).slideDown().addClass('active');
  }

  function close(item) {
    $(item).slideUp().removeClass('active');
  }
}
```